# XSLT - Count preceding within ancestor

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml structure that looks like this simplified:

```xml
<document>
    <page>
        <viewport>
            <text>page1 text1</text>
            <text>page1 text2</text>
            <text>page1 text3</text>
            <viewport>
                <text>page1 text4</text>
                <text>page1 text5</text>
                <text>page1 text6</text>
            </viewport>
        </viewport>
        <viewport>
            <text>page1 text7</text>
            <text>page1 text8</text>
            <text>page1 text9</text>
        </viewport>
    </page>
    <page>
        <viewport>
            <text>page2 text1</text>
            <text>page2 text2</text>
            <text>page2 text3</text>
        </viewport>
        <viewport>
            <text>page2 text4</text>
            <text>page2 text5</text>
            <text>page2 text6</text>
            <viewport>
                <text>page2 text7</text>
                <text>page2 text8</text>
                <text>page2 text9</text>
            </viewport>
        </viewport>
    </page>
</document>
```

I would like to count at how many text elements i am on per page.

My template looks like this

```xml
<xsl:template match="text">
  <xsl:variable name="page-number" select="count(preceding::page) + 1"/>
  <xsl:variable name="position-in-page" select="count(preceding::*[name() = name(current())])"/>
</xsl:template>
```

For an example on `page2 text8` element i want `page-number = 2` and `position-in-page = 8`

I know that `preceding::` is not right here for `position-in-page`...

I think i need a mix of `preceding-sibling` and `ancestor` but i just cant figure out...

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context. An important consideration here is how exactly the template is being applied to the `text` elements, and what is the expected result of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:number count="page"/>
```

for the page number, and:

```
<xsl:number level="any" from="page"/>
```

for the position of text in its page.

This is assuming you want to preserve the internal hierarchy of the viewports. Otherwise this could possibly be much simpler.

Comment: I gave it a quick try and on the first look this seems to be what I was looking for. I will give it a big test tomorrow. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Ok this did the thing! Thank you